# slugify not working in jekyll pages

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, slug

I use jekyll to generate our Webpage ([github link](https://github.com/freifunk-kiel/startseite/blob/master/firmware.html#L86)) which works fine on my developer mashine (Ubuntu 15.10) but doesn't work on two different online servers (Debian wheezy and Ubuntu Serer 14.04)

I tried to install two slugify gems already, but that did not change the behaviour:

```
gem search slugify
gem install jekyll-slugify_underscore
```

the slugify tag seems to be ignored and the links still contain slashes and capital letters...

How can I activate the slugify plugin in jekyll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slugify` filter is part of Jekyll 3.x.

If you want to be sure to work with a correct version of Jekyll, you can use bundler [as it's described here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/).

Comment: I uninstalled jekyll with apt and reinstalled it as gem, which has a newer version. Now it works